# Further clarification needed on someone else's question

Tags: support, specific-question

I was trying to understand the Doppler effect across different mediums on the SE site and came across the question *[Doppler Effect and change in medium](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327387/doppler-effect-and-change-in-medium)*.

Though it's a homework question, I was attempting to understand the solution posted by the OP. Even after rereading and attempting it myself, I am unable to understand the answer posted. I believe the OP is now inactive based on his profile, hence I didn't post my query as a comment. I avoid asking it as a new question as it may be flagged as a duplicate. How can I get the said answer further clarified?

Answer (score 4):

Follow-up questions are fine. Be up-front about it. Clearly state how you understand the existing answers, and what your question is in light of those answers.